# jQuery does not fire when changing the anchor link in the URL... How can I capture this event?

Tags: jquery, anchor, jquery-events

I have a page with accordion-type subsections which are toggled open by clicking on the section title or by clicking a link from a dropdown in the global site navigation.

The intention is to make sections within the page accessible directly from anywhere.

The global menu has links in the format of:

```
/pagename.aspx#anchor-name
/pagename.aspx#anchor-name2
```

To capture clicks via the global navigation, I use:

```
var anchor = window.location.hash;

if (anchor) {
    toggle_element(anchor_name);
}
```

within

```
$(document).ready
```

Unfortunately `.ready` fires only the first time the page is loaded.

If I navigate to click on `/pagename.aspx#anchor-name`, my script runs. If I then click on `/pagename.aspx#anchor-name2`, nothing happens.

How can I capture this activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
window.onhashchange = anchor_change;

function anchor_change() {...}
```

based on this [MozDev's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.onhashchange) and http://caniuse.com/hashchange showing that it is supported in IE8 and above along with most contemporary browsers which covers my use case.

Note that IE8 could not understand the `window.addEventListener("hashchange", anchor_change, false);` format, so I had to use the `window.onchange = anchor_change;` variation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to hash-change event with this jQuery plugin
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the plugin and noticed that it has not been updated since 2010. I decided to look for a simpler solution and leave the plugin as a plan B option.